# What is the best way to store ip addresses in application?

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2

Im developing an application based on Spring and JSF 2.0. There is a requirement to remember how many times client from specific ip address tried to submit form during last 3 minutes. If during 3 minutes more than 3 submit attempts were recorded then captcha should be displayed.

Im thinking about using `ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Long>>` for storing ip address (`String`) and submit time (milis) in queue (`ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Long>`). The queue will be cleaned by Quartz in 3-min intervals (milis older than 3-min will be removed). To check if display captcha I will check if queue size > 3.

Is this correct approach? Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: Will you need to search by IP ranges?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java provides a special class for storing IP addresses: [`java.net.InetAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html). Unlike `Long`, it is capable of handling 128-bit addresses in addition to 32-bit ones, and it is not as wasteful as a `String` in terms of the memory that it uses, which might become important in very high-volume situations.

Comment: OK, what about concept of storing submit times in ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Long> and cleaning it by Quartz in 3min intervals, is it ok?

Comment: @michal777 No, you should be clearing it every minute, not every three minutes. Consider this: at the time the cleanup job runs you have a two-minute-old request, which is kept in the queue. In two more minutes the request would remain in the queue, even though it's now four-minutes old. An alternative would be to test the age of items in the queue in addition to checking queue size to be greater than 3.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I store my IP's as Longs rather than Strings.

You will see a performance improvement.